# Trying to setup a small Kafka cluster on bare metal using Kraft

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

"Why bare metal?" - It's a company limitation/bureaucracy.

I'm trying to startup a Kafka Cluster on a single machine for the sake of learning before trying to send things to production.

My goal is to setup 1 Controller, 1 Broker,Controller and 1 Broker. I'm editing directly the `server.properties` file.

Here is the code for the Controller

```
process.roles=controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9193,2@localhost:9293
listeners=CONTROLLER1://localhost:9193
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER1
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER1:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER2:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER3:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Here is the code for the Broker,Controller

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=2
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9193,2@localhost:9293
listeners=CONTROLLER2://localhost:9293,BROKER2://localhost:9292
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER2
listener.security.protocol.map=BROKER2:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER2:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=BROKER2://localhost:9292
inter.broker.listener.name=BROKER2
```

And here is the code for the Broker

```
process.roles=broker
node.id=3
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9193,2@localhost:9293
listeners=BROKER3://localhost:9392
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER1
listener.security.protocol.map=BROKER3:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER1:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
inter.broker.listener.name=BROKER3
advertised.listeners=BROKER3://localhost:9392
```

The rest of the settings are pretty much default.

I am able to run all 3 of them using the CLI command and they seem to start without any errors

```
bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t ffQlsx4mQn-ipKduywm2Ig -c config/server.properties --ignore-formatted
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

However, the issue I'm getting is when I try to produce/consume messages to a test topic (I'm running with `num.partitions=10`)

```
[2023-09-12 11:32:13,844] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] 10 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [test-4, test-7, test-14, test-9, test-3, test-16, test-0, test-10, test-18, test-13] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

```
[2023-09-12 11:32:10,709] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-96466] 10 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [test-4, test-7, test-14, test-9, test-3, test-16, test-0, test-10, test-18, test-13] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

The CLI commands are

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9292 --topic test`

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9292 --topic test --from-beginning`

If I try and list existing topics (`bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9292`), I can see that my test topic was created on both my brokers (9292 and 9392) but the error persists.

Can anybody point me to the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using:

- Kafka 3.5.1 from the Kafka official page. Binary Download. Scala 2.13
- Ubuntu 22.04
- openjdk 11.0.20.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listeners should all have the same names. Don't number them

For instance, `inter.broker.listener.name` is used for replication, and must match for partitions to be replicated.

Similarly for the controller, the Kraft protocol will become confused in leader election events when `controller.listener.names` are different between any two nodes in the quorum voters list.